# Calling a parent class constructor from a child class in python

Tags: python, inheritance

So if I have a class:

```
 class Person(object):
'''A class with several methods that revolve around a person's Name and Age.'''

    def __init__(self, name = 'Jane Doe', year = 2012):
        '''The default constructor for the Person class.'''
        self.n = name
        self.y = year
```

And then this subclass:

```
 class Instructor(Person):
'''A subclass of the Person class, overloads the constructor with a new parameter.'''
     def __init__(self, name, year, degree):
         Person.__init__(self, name, year)
```

I'm a bit lost on how to get the subclass to call and use the parent class constructor for `name` and `year`, while adding the new parameter `degree` in the subclass.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: what you are doing should be fine ...

Comment: Oh, ok, I wasn't sure and I couldn't figure out a way to test it... I see that I was correct all along... my apologies.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Python recommends using `super()`.

Python 2:

```
super(Instructor, self).__init__(name, year)
```

Python 3:

```
super().__init__(name, year)
```

Comment: The only problem I encountered while using super __init__ approach is, it doesn't return me the instance of parent class. Thus in case a 3rd parameter is deduced based on name and year inside the parent init method, child object doesn't get access to that 3rd parameter as__init__ doesn't return it. So I prefer calling Person(name, year) from Instructor

Comment: There is no "instance of parent class". There is only one instance, it is the one that is being initialized, and usually it is called "self".

Comment: @AlwaysanewComer Then you did not call the superclass constructor at all (not explicitly at least) but instantiated a new object from the superclass instead.