# How can I add attributes to a derivated class?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def hablar(self, message):
        print(message)


class Alien(Human):
    def __init__(self, planet):
        self.planet = planet

    def fly(self):
        print("I'm flying!")
```

This code is an example to show what I want to do. Imagine that I want an alien to inheritance all the properties of a Human but I also want him to have a planet attribute to distinguish from which planet does it comes.

When I do it as I did it in the mentioned code, it didn't work. Is it possible to do it? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557612/calling-a-parent-class-constructor-from-a-child-class-in-python) about calling parent class constructor from a child class.

You need to use the dunder method `__init__` of the parent class inside the `__init__` of `Alien` as so:

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def hablar(self, message):
        print(str(message))


class Alien(Human):

    def __init__(self, name, age, planet):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.planet = planet

    def fly(self):
        print("I'm flying!")
```

Comment: Refer here  please 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557612/calling-a-parent-class-constructor-from-a-child-class-in-python

Comment: Like so `alien = Alien("ET", "99", "Somewhere")` for instance.

Comment: Should the super class constructor be called before the base class variables are assigned or the other way around? What's the convention?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the constructor of the parent class.

```
class Alien(Human):
    def __init__(self, name, age, planet):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.planet = planet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age

class Alien(Human):
    def __init__(self, planet, **kwargs):
        self.planet = planet
        super(Alien, self).__init__(**kwargs)


Z = Alien(planet='Venus',name='Z',age=21)
print(Z.__dict__)
```

output:

```
{'planet': 'Venus', 'name': 'Z', 'age': 21}
```